# How can I categorize the apps on my phone?

Tags: applications

I'm downloading many apps but then forget about them. I'd like to be able to see all my "note taking" apps, "todo" apps etc. So I can quickly compare and discard those I don't want. Of course I'd also like all "game" apps so I can choose which game to play.

How can I do that so it is automatic (maybe use the information in market?). Is there a way to tag apps so they can belong to several categories?

Answer (score 11):

There is an app called [Apps Organizer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.code.appsorganizer) that will let you "tag" applications into groups.  You can then put folder widgets on your homescreen of each of these "tags" to stay organized.  I've used it before, it works well if you keep your tags up to date.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there would be a reliable way to do it automatically, but [App Manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=program.main) claims to do this.

I group the apps I use on my home screens, so that games are on one screen and apps on another, with related apps in the same row (e.g. instant messengers).  You could do something similar.

You could also create folders and put your apps in them.  I believe App Manager can help you do that as well.

Answer (score 4):

[ADW Launcher](http://market.android.com/details?id=org.adw.launcher) lets you group apps in the app drawer.   I have a group setup for Games and an icon on my home screen that shows that group.

Answer (score 3):

In case if your phone is from HTC (and has HTC Sense launcher) you may add a folder on any page, like "Todo", "Games", "Internet", "New apps", etc.

I use this approach in my case, and I add every new application to the "New apps" folder just after install.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I don't think there's a way to "tag" apps but</strike> Apparently you can (see [Bryan's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7413/how-can-i-categorize-my-apps/7418#7418)).

*The rest of my original answer:* You can create folders on the home screen, label it "Games" or "Notes" and put shortcuts to apps in there.  To do this long press on the home screen select "Folders", then "Add Folders", then "New Folder" (steps may be slightly different on your phone).  Once the folder is on your home screen you can then drag an app on top of it to add it to the folder.  To rename the folder: open the folder and then long press on the title bar of the folder at the top - after a few seconds a dialog will pop up to allow you to rename your folder.

Hope this helps

*Edit* - I was in the process of editing my answer to include what Matthew said about grouping apps on different home screens - but he beat me to it :).  I use this method for games where I have all my games on one home screen.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Folder Organizer Lite](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.abcOrganizer.lite). It's an extended version of Apps Organizer. It lets you not only tag apps, but also bookmarks and contacts. It's free.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [TagHome Launcher](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.stain46.taghome) (freeware)
It's quite easy to use: you can create as many tags as you want and assign (zero or more of) these tags to applications; all new apps are falling into "no tags" category and are easy to spot and assign tags to.
The launcher isn't flashy, but it's quite fast; I've tried several top rated ones before choosing TagHome